# Run some functions after activating virtual environment from the same script contain the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, virtualenv

I need to run some functions after activating the virtual environment.
I want to activate the virtual env from the same script which is containing the functions.

I am using the following code :

```
if 'VUNET_VIRT_ENV' in os.environ:
            VUNET_VIRT_ENV = os.environ['VUNET_VIRT_ENV']
else:
    VUNET_VIRT_ENV = '/home/ubuntu/workspace/vunetenv/'
    
VIRTENV_ACTIVATE_FILE = VUNET_VIRT_ENV + 'bin/activate_this.py'

exec(compile(open(VIRTENV_ACTIVATE_FILE).read(),
             VIRTENV_ACTIVATE_FILE,
             'exec'))
```

I am getting the following error while running the script:

```
Command '' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

there is activate_this.py in the defined location. But I can't figure out what went wrong? I am running in Linux.

Comment: I never heard that one could activate an environment from *within* a running python interpreter session. Maybe you can activate the environment and run the python code from a shell script?

Comment: try to run it mannully and see where you're getting the error

Comment: @NilsL. See these searches: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+%22activate_this.py%22), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+activate+script). This is a perfectly valid technique.

Comment: @phd that is interesting, thank you for the tip!